# почему label не реагирует на стили?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Подскажите почему не реагирует на стили `label`? По разметке не кричите, так сделано в плагине, пытаюсь его изменить.

Стили для чекбокса

```
.checkbox {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox > input {
    position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.checkbox::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    left: 3px;
    top: 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #D35932;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
}

.checkbox::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #D35932;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.checkbox input:checked + .checkbox::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox input:checked {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**html**

```
<label class="checkbox">
  ::before
  <input type="checkbox" name="leyka_agree" class="leyka_agree required" value="1" id="leyka_agree">
  <span class="leyka-checkbox-label"> Соглашаюсь с <a class="leyka-legal-terms-trigger" href="#"> офертой                  
     </a>
 </span>
  ::after
</label>
```

после нажатия `after` не появляется, даже добавил проверку без плюса все работает, проблема именно когда `input:checked + .checkbox::after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В css нет такого селектора чтобы при состоянии дочернего элемента изменять состоянии родительского. Но зато можно менять вложенные элементы или элементы которые находятся у одного родителя (siblings).

Ваш исправленный пример:
codepen.io/kirya-dev/pen/poNNLJq

Comment: _"В css нет такого селектора чтобы при состоянии дочернего элемента изменять состоянии родительского."_ Один всё же есть, просто в данном случае, не подходит.